# Capture group nam and items with String#scan

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like that :

```
group1
  Members: 
  m/a
  m/b
group2
  Members: 
  m/c
  m/d
  m/e
group3
  No Members
```

I want to have a scan result like :

```
[["group1","a","b"],["group2","c","d","e"],["group3"]]
```

But I just can have :

```
[["group1","a"],["group2","c"],["group3", nil]]
```

with this regexp :

```
text.scan(/([^\r\n]+)\r?\n[\s\t]*(?:No |)Members[\s:]*\r?\n(?:[\t\s]*m\/(\w+)+\r?\n)*/m)
```

Can I do what I want only with regexp ?

Comment: If you are just keeping the idea of doing it in two steps and are not particularly satisfied with my answer, I will delete it. Let me know in case you are willing to accept it, and I will undelete my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to do it in a regex, it gets unwieldy, so I'd do it this way:

```
data = <<EOT
group1
  Members: 
  m/a
  m/b
group2
  Members: 
  m/c
  m/d
  m/e
group3
  No Members
EOT

pp data.lines.slice_before(/^group/).to_a
=> [["group1\n", "  Members: \n", "  m/a\n", "  m/b\n"],
    ["group2\n", "  Members: \n", "  m/c\n", "  m/d\n", "  m/e\n"],
    ["group3\n", "  No Members\n"]]
```

Cleaning up the rest to meet the question's requirements makes it:

```
data.gsub(%r{\bm/}, '').split(/\n\s*/).reject{ |s| s[/\bMembers\b/] }.slice_before(/^group/).to_a
=> [["group1", "a", "b"], ["group2", "c", "d", "e"], ["group3"]]
```

The gist of the parsing is really in `slice_before`. Everything else is creating the array and cleanup.

Breaking it down:

- `gsub(%r{\bm/}, '')` strips the undesired `m/`.
- `split(/\n\s*/)` splits the string on line-ends into an array, while simultaneously removing the leading white-space.
- `reject{ |s| s[/\bMembers\b/] }` rejects any lines containing 'Members' as a separate word.
- `slice_before(/^group/)` breaks up the array into chunks starting with 'group' at the beginning of the string.
- `to_a` converts it all into an array again.

Comment: Thank you for your code. But I would like to use regexp only if possible for performance reason (the input can be much larger than my example)...

Comment: Performance reasons? Do you have benchmarks showing which is the best way? Simply because it's a regex is no guarantee it's going to be faster, especially since you haven't got a working regex yet. @sawa had a good, working solution, which was fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store hierarchical data like that, you might be better off using YAML instead of trying to parse a string with a regex.

groups.yml:

```
group1:
  members: 
  - m/a
  - m/b
group2:
  members: 
  - m/c
  - m/d
  - m/e
group3:
  members: []
```

Parsing this data:

```
> YAML.load(File.open('./groups.yml'))
 => {"group1"=>{"members"=>["m/a", "m/b"]}, "group2"=>{"members"=>["m/c", "m/d", "m/e"]}, "group3"=>{"members"=>[]}}
```

Comment: It looks like a yaml file, but it is not. I have tried anyway, but got a syntax error from the default yaml parser of ruby.

Comment: It wasn't clear, but the text to be parsed come from an external API, I don't generate it.